# What driver is compatibility with USB\VID_0FE6&PID_9700&REV_0101 hardware id?

Tags: drivers, lan

I use windows server 2016 and external lan card.

Hardware Id is : USB\VID_0FE6&PID_9700&REV_0101.
I test several driver but does not work.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 2):

That PNP ID appears to be a Realtek RTL8150.

Have you tried drivers from  [this page](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100m-fast-ethernet-usb-2-0-software)  or  [this driver](https://download.cnet.com/Realtek-RTL8150-USB-10-100-Fast-Ethernet-Adapter/3000-2112_4-186650.html)  hosted by cnet?